# HT Access URL re write

Tags: .htaccess

I am having trouble re directing my news pages using .htaccess. 
I display news from a php script inside the folder news called new_item.php, i get the id= query string and query the database. I am now changing my news links to "mysite/news/$id/news_title" how can I do this I have tried the code below with .htaccess with no success.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule    ^news/([0-9]+)/(.*)$    ^news_item.php?id=$1
```

Comment: What is your desired effect and what actually happens?

Comment: Desired effect:

From: news/news_item.php?id=14&lang=en
To: news/14/medcomms-products-and-services-on-display/

Currently I am getting a 404

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/.+$ /news/news_item.php?id=$1&lang=en [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Can you look into your Apache error.log and tell me what is the error.

Comment: "http://www.vallettaboatshow.com/our-partners.php?lang=en" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36"
74.208.238.172 - - [16/Jul/2013:07:20:07 -0500] "HEAD /dotnetnuke/KeepAlive.aspx HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "-"

Comment: This is a 404 error line not 500 error line. Pls tail the error.log while you do this test to capture the correct error line.

Comment: 92.251.127.152 - - [16/Jul/2013:06:28:40 -0500] "GET /news/news_item.php?id=14&lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 3016

Comment: That is status 200 which means OK.

Comment: Also this appears to be access.log. Can you check error.log instead?